# Singular cohomology of fields.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

Given a complex variety $X$ over $\mathbb{C}$, let $F(X)$ be its function field. Define the singular cohomology of $F(X)$ as the colimit of singular cohomology of all Zariski opens of $X$. Is there a way to get an idea of what the singular cohomology of function field looks like? Even in the simple cases when $X$ is an affine space? When $X$ is just $\mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{C}}$, it easy to see that by removing each point you are adding a generator to the cohomology, so the first cohomology will be $\mathbb{Z}^{\oplus \infty}$. For higher dimensions I am having a hard time calculating it. I was wondering whether it is true that higher cohomology groups of a function field is generated by the first cohomology group by the cup product or not?

Comment: Well in your example, the first thing I notice is that $\mathbb A^1$ minus some points has the homotopy type of a CW-complex of dimension $1,$ hence the higher cohomology of $\mathbb C(x)$ is trivial.

Comment: You're right that it has topological dimension 2, but when you subtract $k$ points, the resulting space has the homotopy type of a bouquet of $k$ circles. You get nontrivial first cohomology, but zero cohomology in higher degrees.